# How to identify my search conditions for Primary Keys and Foreign Key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

I am trying to run a constraint code to show the name,type,owner and search condition but the search condition field is left empty for my primary and foreign keys.

Here is my create table code :

```
CREATE TABLE sal_history_2018 
(empid NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, 
first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
hire_date DATE NOT NULL, 
sal NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT sal_history_2018_pk PRIMARY KEY(empid,hire_date),
CONSTRAINT sal_history_2018_fk FOREIGN KEY(empid) REFERENCES employees_2018(employee_no))
```

Here is my constraints code :

```
select constraint_name, constraint_type, owner, search_condition
from user_constraints
where table_name='SAL_HISTORY_2018'
```

I am trying to get the search conditions for my PK and FK to appear as NOT NULL like the other values in this screenshot.

Constraints code result:

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

In the attached image, "search condition" is an unusual way of describing what is really the constraint on the data being applied by a check constraint (CONSTRAINT_TYPE of "C").

Primary and Foreign Keys constrains do not have such a condition. they express a different form of constraint that for the primary key means "All values must be present and unique" and for the foreign key means "All values must appear in the referenced column(s)".

So the "not null" condition is implicitly implied by the primary key columns by the presence of the primary key, but also by the presence of a not-null check constraints on the columns.

The foreign key itself does not imply "not null", but that is already a constraint on the individual columns themselves.

Comment: So I dont actually need it to show not null in either PK or FK search condition because that is already implied ?  just so im clear

Comment: It is implied for a PK certainly, but it's really only a valid concept for check constraints.

Comment: alright cheers for the help i get the feeling my lecturer will have a negative view on my explanation!

Comment: Well, although you can have multicolumn constraint, like "date_of_death >= date_of_birth", check constraints are conceptually different to UK, PK, or FK as they are strictly "inter-row" – they only consider data from the same row in the same table. UK, FK and PK are intra-row, in that they compare the data of multiple rows against each other (and FK can, but does not have to be, inter-table). So that conceptual difference might help explain why a check condition can have different attributes to the others.